# Error while publishing website in IIS7

Tags: c#, asp.net, text, web

How do i add a New Line `"\n"` in the text box I had created in asp.net web site.
For instance

```
TextBoxA.Text="Hello";
TextBoxB.Text="World";
TextBoxC="Hello
     World"
```

Like:

```
TextBoxC.Text=TextBoxA.Text+"\n"(or something)+TextBoxB.Text;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TextBoxC.Text= string.Format("{0}\n{1}", TextBoxA.Text,TextBoxB.Text);
```

or

```
TextBoxC.Text= TextBoxA.Text + "\n" + TextBoxB.Text;
```

Now, for this to work you have to make the textbox multiline...

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxC" runat="server" TextMode="MutiLine" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use texmode of your textbox.

Add TextMode to multiline.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="MyBox" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10" />
```